# Como sobrepor um método da superclasse usando um parâmetro polimórfico?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma superclasse abstrata `Service` com um método abstrato  `onExecute(ServiceData data)` que é sobreposto na subclasse `EchoService`. Porém, nesse método sobreposto, eu preciso que o parâmetro seja uma subclasse de `ServiceData`. Ao tentar fazer isso o Java diz que eu não sobrepus o método da superclasse. Pelo que me lembro de quando estudei programação orientada à objetos eu aprendi que uma subclasse pode ser passada onde se espera uma superclasse. Não entendi porque isso não funcionou.

Essas são minhas classes:

```
public abstract class ServiceData { /*...*/ }
public class EchoData extends ServiceData { /*...*/ }

public abstract class Service {
  protected abstract ServiceResponse onExecute(ServiceData data) throws Exception;
}

public class EchoService extends Service {
  @Override
  protected ServiceResponse onExecute(EchoData data) throws Exception {
    return null;
  }
}
```

O erro:

> Class 'EchoService' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onExecute(ServiceData)' in 'StilingueService'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Diretamente assim não tem como porque a linguagem não faz covariância automática. Você pode fazer isso com *generics*. Vou colocar aqui um código a grosso modo, não quer dizer que ele compile exatamente assim (eu sei fazer em C#, não em Java, mas deve ser bem parecido):

```
public abstract class ServiceData { /*...*/ }
public class EchoData extends ServiceData { /*...*/ }
public abstract class Service<T extends ServiceData> {
      protected abstract ServiceResponse onExecute(T data) throws Exception;
}
public class EchoService extends Service<EchoData> {
    @Override
    protected ServiceResponse onExecute(EchoData data) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/GenericInharitance.java).

Parto do princípio que `EchoData` deriva de `ServiceData`.

Comment: Sua solução funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de fazer uma POC seguindo o que o @alandplm sugeriu na resposta, mudando o objeto **EchoData** para **ServiceData** e *executando um métodos que foi implementado em EchoData*.

Para conseguir executar esse método, eu assumi que existia ele fazendo cast.

Ficou assim:

```
public class EchoData extends ServiceData {
        public EchoData() {
            super();
        }

        public void teste() {
            System.out.println("teste");
        }
    }

@Override
    protected ServiceResponse onExecute(ServiceData data) throws Exception {
        ((EchoData) data).teste();
        return null;
    }
```

Main de teste:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            EchoData echoData = new EchoData() ;
            EchoService teste = new EchoService();
            teste.onExecute(echoData);
        }
```

Saída no console:

```
teste
```

**Essa solução acima, vai compilar, mesmo que seja passada um objeto do tipo ServiceData. Não aconselho o uso por ficar uma brecha no código, mesmo compilando. Porém, mostra que é possível essa implementação!**

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Agora passa um `ServiceData` que não seja um `EchoData`. O primeiro teste que se faz é o que não funciona direito.

Comment: Sim, ai teremos um ClassCastException. Nessa POC que testei assumi o risco de não ter o método. Mas você tem razão, há erro em tempo de execução!

Comment: Realmente isso funciona, mas o ruim dessa solução é que as classes terão que ficar fazendo casts toda hora.

Comment: Sim... Não é a melhor solução (sem dúvida), mas a carácter de estudo é interessante. Há questões para certificação que são assim. O código compila e é questionado o que irá acontece caso seja passado como parâmetro uma classe do tipo ServiceData.

Answer (score 0):

Em `protected ServiceResponse onExecute(EchoData data) throws Exception` você precisa tornar o parametro `Data` do tipo `ServiceData`. Isso não interferirá no uso, uma vez que na hora de usar o método você poderá passar um objeto do tipo `EchoData` sem problema.

Esta questão é abordada na especificação do Java na [seção 8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3). É relevante o entendimento do [Princípio de Liskov](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov) e o funcionamento de Tipos de Retorno Covariantes e Tipos de Parâmetros Contravariantes.

Comment: Mas no método `onExecute(EchoData data)` de `EchoService` eu preciso chamar um método que existe em `EchoData` mas não existe em `ServiceData`. É justamente este o problema